# Cocos2d v3: How do you draw an arc?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I want to draw a filled arc like this:

[image]

`CCDrawNode` only contain methods to draw a circle, a polygon or a line – but no arc.

To be clear, I'm wanting to be able to generate the arc at runtime, with an arbitrary radius and arc angle.

**My Question:**

Is there a way to have Cocos2d draw an arc, or would I have to do it myself with OpenGL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you can use the `CCProgressNode`, and by setting the sprite to an orange circle, you can draw an arc by setting the progress property.

Now, whether you can set the sprite as a vectorized circle that you can just scale, I am not really sure.

Personally, I'd suggest you add the drawing arc code to `CCDrawNode`, and submit a PR.

Comment: Thanks. The `CCProgressNode` worked, although I haven't been able to work out (maybe you can't) use a `CCDrawNode` for the sprite in the CCProgressNode. My workaround is simply to have a handful of circle images as PNGs, and just create a sprite with the one that's about the right size and scale appropriately. This is fine for my current purposes. Thanks.

Comment: FYI to anyone who's using CCProgressNode, unlike most percentage figures in Cocos2D which are from 0 to 1.0, the `percentage` property in `CCProgressNode` is from 0 to 100.0.

Answer (score 0):

tested using cocos2dx v3.8, codes from DrawNode::drawSolidCircle

```
DrawNode* Pie::drawPie(const Vec2& center, float radius, float startAngle, float endAngle, unsigned int segments, float scaleX, float scaleY, const Color4F &color){
    segments++;
    auto draw = DrawNode::create();
    const float coef = (endAngle - startAngle) / segments;

    Vec2 *vertices = new (std::nothrow) Vec2[segments];
    if (!vertices)
        return nullptr;

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < segments - 1; i++)
    {
        float rads = i*coef;
        GLfloat j = radius * cosf(rads + startAngle) * scaleX + center.x;
        GLfloat k = radius * sinf(rads + startAngle) * scaleY + center.y;

        vertices[i].x = j;
        vertices[i].y = k;
    }

    vertices[segments - 1].x = center.x;
    vertices[segments - 1].y = center.y;

    draw->drawSolidPoly(vertices, segments, color);

    CC_SAFE_DELETE_ARRAY(vertices);

    return draw;
}
```

call it like

```
auto pie = Pie::drawPie(_visibleSize / 2, _visibleSize.width / 4, 0, 1, 999, 1, 1, Color4F::BLUE);
```